# Detect connectivity change within Android Activity subclass

Tags: java, android, networking, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I'm relatively new to Android,

I have read related articles on detecting network connectivity changes and have implemented  this `BroadcastReceiver` subclass, made the necessary additions to AndroidManifest.xml and I receive the requisite state change broadcasts as expected:

```
public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

Question is: how can I receive or forward these notifications in/to my `Activity` subclasses? Apparently creating an instance of `NetworkStateReceiver` in my `Activity` subclass and overriding `onReceive` there doesn't do the trick.

Thanks in advance for any pointers...

**Edit:**

I ended up broadcasting an `Intent` from `onReceive` above like so:

```
Intent target = new Intent(CONNECTIVITY_EVENT);
target.putExtra(CONNECTIVITY_STATE, networkInfo.isConnected());
context.sendBroadcast(target);
```

And receiving that in my `Activity` like so:

```
@Override
protected String[] notifyStrings() {
     return ArrayUtils.addAll(super.notifyStrings(), new String[] {NetworkStateReceiver.CONNECTIVITY_EVENT});
}

@Override
protected void notifyEvent(Intent intent, String action) {
    super.notifyEvent(intent, action);
    if (action != null) {
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(NetworkStateReceiver.CONNECTIVITY_EVENT)) {
            boolean isConnected = intent.getBooleanExtra(NetworkStateReceiver.CONNECTIVITY_STATE, true);
            // Do something...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using either
1) An interface approach. So declare an interface that has a `networkChanged()` method, and have the class which owns this `BroadcastReceiver` keep a list of classes who want to be notified of network changes with a local `List<InterfaceName>`

2) Skip the interface creating and use a subscription utility. My two favorites are
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

and

https://gist.github.com/bclymer/6708819  (smaller, less used, also disclaimer: I wrote this)

With these you would create event classes with properties, and then subscribe and post instances of those classes.

In your activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    ...
    EventBus.getInstance().subscribe(this, MyType.class);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    ...
    EventBus.getInstance().unsubscribe(this, MyType.class);
}

@Override
public void newEvent(Object event) {
    if (event instanceOf MyType) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

And then in your `BroadcastReceiver`

```
@Override 
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    EventBus.post(new MyType(true));
}
```

Example MyType

```
public class MyType {
    public boolean networkEnabled;
    public MyType(boolean networkEnabled) {
        this.networkEnabled = networkEnabled;
    }
}
```

This examples use the 2nd subscription utility (mine).